# Matching pairs and triplet substrings from a string

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have a system where a string will be received from the user. I have a list of words which basically classifies what category that word belongs to. This will look something like this:

```
classifier = {"delhi":"place",
"new-delhi":"place",
"java":"skill",
"python":"skill"}
```

Suppose the query comes out to be `java jobs in new delhi`. What I have thought of implementing is given below:

- Slugify the string
- Pick triplets from string like (0,1,2),(1,2,3) and so on.
- If a triplet is mapped into the `classifier` dict,pop it from the string,store it and continue with the processing.

Similarly the task will be repeated for pairs and singles.

The above method will give me complexity of around 3n where n is the length of the string.

Is there any other/better way of doing this?

Comment: As a suggestion, maybe delegate the search process to a dedicated tool like redis, cassandra or aerospike ...

Comment: I have a Solr server set up for search. I just want to be able to classify data so that I can apply filters on the go.

Comment: How about building an indexed `classifier` first? Something like `{"places_index": {'a': ["a1", "a2"..]}}` and then search for a query part there `if 'java' in classifier['skills_index']['j']`

Comment: Suppose I have 200 skills starting with the letter 'j' and 200 locations starting with 'j', I'll have to iterate 400 times to check if java is a skill or a location. Better would be to keep a dictionary, as that would provide me constant lookup time.